# How to change foreground colour in a cell in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change text color in a c# data table. Now I need to know how to change foreground(text) color in a particular cell in that table.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//some code here
//lets say the cell is [0,0]
//change the foregroud color like this

table.columns[0].rows[0].forgroundColor ="red";
```

Comment: What is `DataTable`? Is it `System.Data.DataTable`?

Comment: what are you doing by applying color to DataTable?

Comment: Flagged this question. This needs more focus.. too late I saw this is 6 years old. Anyway, to answer this, we need the platform more accurate (asp.net, or MVC ?) and it is not clear *where* the color needs to be changed. Database tables have no colors, unless you specify a field for it. Above code works in the database, on field "forgroundcolor" you set a string "red".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
table.Columns[0].Rows[0].ForegroundColor = Color.Red;
```

## Edit

I may have jumped the gun when I gave my original answer. I think what you're doing is trying to set the color of a `System.Data.DataTable`. This will never work as this object represents the collection of data and not the actual control.

I think  what you actually want is something like a `DataGrid` (*depending on what technology you're using*). You can then style this control accordingly after you've bound the `DataTable` to it.

Comment: What technology are you using? WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Data table to grid or some where other wise you cannot do color cell in datatable..

1.First create a table style

```
TableItemStyle tableCellStyle = new TableItemStyle();
tableCellStyle.ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

2. Now apply this style to any cell object

   Cell.ApplyStyle( tableCellStyle);

Now i think you can manage your code according to your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Apply any style to any cell, only imagination is limit

add a 'style' column to datatable

```
     DataSeta.BalanceSheetRow AssetsStockRow = (DataSeta.BalanceSheetRow)BalanceSheet.NewRow();
     AssetsStockRow.CurrentAssetACC = "Stock Value";
     AssetsStockRow.CurrentAssetAmt = Common.ConvertToDouble(stockValue.ToString()).ToString("00.00");
     AssetsStockRow.style = "style=\"color: gray;\"";
     BalanceSheet.Rows.Add(AssetsStockRow);
```

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Assests" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div <%#Eval("style") %>><%#Eval("CurrentAssetACC") %></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```